# What style of make up does Dethklok wear when performing?

Tags: metalocalypse

On the show Metalocalypse the band Dethklok usually wears a specific make-up style when performing their shows.  It appears as white skin tones with blacked out eyes and ash around the eye black.  Is there a name for this style of make-up? It seems similar to other real bands like Cradle of Filth but not quite as influenced by the band Kiss

Comment: Knowing that the show is about an over-the-top Death Metal band, I can understand the question but is there a way you can word it to make it less trivia-like and more about the reason for the make-up and what it is lampooning?

Comment: The reason they wear it is the same that any band adds theatricality to their stage performances, to add something to draw the fans. That's not what I'm asking, I just want to know if there is a name for that style of make up, either general or specific (preferably specific)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial searching almost had me convinced there was not a name for it, but alas, it is called corpse paint or corpsepaint. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpse_paint):

> Corpse paint or corpsepaint is a style of black-and-white makeup, used
>   mainly by black metal bands during live concerts and photo shoots. The
>   makeup is used to intensify the bands' imagery of evil, inhumanity,
>   and corpse-like decay. It is most commonly worn just on the face, but
>   in some rare occasions is also applied on arms and torso and in even
>   rarer occasions, some musicians use other colors than just black and
>   white.

If you do a google image search for corpsepaint you get lots and lots of examples! Here is Brendon Small, the creator of Metalocalypse who occasionally tours as Dethklok, in corpsepaint:

[image]